# Finding projection of a matrix on to a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, projection-matrices

I have a convex set $A$ defined as the set of symmetric matrices with entries containing values [-1,1].

I want to find the projection of another matrix $X$ on to $A$.  Can anyone suggest a method to do it ?.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $Y \in A$ which is the solution of the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min & \quad \sum_{i,j} (X_{ij} - Y_{ij})^2 \\
\text{s.t.} & \quad -1 \le Y_{ij} \le 1, \quad \forall i,j \\
& \quad Y_{ij} = Y_{ji}, \quad \forall i,j.
\end{align}

For the case $i=j$ it is simply
$$
Y_{ii} = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if $X_{ii} > 1$}, \\
X_{ii}, & \text{ if $X_{ii} \in [-1, 1]$ }, \\
-1, & \text{ if $X_{ii} < 1$}.
\end{cases}
$$

For the case $i \ne j$, $Y_{ij} = Y_{ji}$ is the solution of the following 
$ \min_{Y_{ij} \in [-1, 1]} \ (X_{ij} - Y_{ij})^2 + (X_{ji} - Y_{ij})^2$, using method of Lagrange multiplier, we have 
$$
Y_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if $X_{ij} + X_{ji} > 2$}, \\
\frac{X_{ij} + X_{ji}}{2}, & \text{ if $X_{ij} + X_{ji} \in [-2, 2]$}, \\
-1, & \text{ if $X_{ij} + X_{ji} < -2$}.
\end{cases}
$$